# Removing image based on type of device with js and class

Tags: javascript, android, ios

I have a website where I want the app store button to be present only on apple devices. Same with google play button on android devices. I think the simplest way would be to use some js to hide an image based on device used.

I'm a noob at js, but could you do something with code like:

`if device == "iPhone3,1" {
    imageview.hidden = true
}`

If so, where do I add this and how do I link it to a specific image if the images class is 'app-btn' ?

Comment: This question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3514784/what-is-the-best-way-to-detect-a-mobile-device-in-jquery has some good answers

Answer (score 0):

try something like this:

```
if(/iPhone|iPad|iPod/i.test(navigator.userAgent))
    document.body.classList.add("ios");
else if(/Android/i.test(navigator.userAgent))
    document.body.classList.add("android");
```

now the `<body>` tag has an android or ios class, use css to display or not the images.